# Being prompted for an administrators password for Ubuntu 12.04 but I never set one?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords

I’m working on a Acer Chromebook CB3-531 and installed Ubuntu 12.04 XFCE.  Almost everytime I attempt to install and/or open any package(file) I’m getting the message:

> You need to grant administrative rights to install software.

That followed by a prompt to enter the administrator’s password. I didn’t set one, but I have tried every password I know. I’ve read every solution I can find all to no avail.

While there seem to be an abundance of remedies for Windows, there are but a few for the Chrome OS, also I have Powerwash, used the recovery disk, both many times, tried the default administrator’s password `test0000` nothing works. I’ve also started the installation from scratch a number of times.

Can’t there be someone who has solved this. Please help, please, please, please.

Comment: My only advice is, if you don't know the password, reset the device's configuration

Comment: use the "root login". search Distro support site for clues... or use Mint instead

Answer (score 0):

Enable Root Login via LightDM:

First of all, enable root user by giving a password. In terminal execute:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Enter current user password and then input a root password twice.

Then, edit the

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

By your favorite editor and add this line:

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

Now, reboot! In login screen, there’s a more option “Login” which promts to input username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You likely never set an administrator password that’s why you don’t know what it is.

Now I don’t know what application is asking you for the root password, but you will need to set one before you can provide it.

In a terminal type the following…

First, this will request your user password:

```
sudo su
```

And this will let you set a root password:

```
passwd
```

Comment: djsmiley2k...sudo su #

Comment: This is all new to me...but I just wanted to say your answer is what worked for me. My best to you.                        Ray Zimmerman

Comment: What can I say Jake Gould...thanks to all of you, it was so kind the way most of you came to my aid. The situation was indeed correctly answered...but it is beyond me "to check the answer off as such."  Or to even "up votei it" what is a up vote anyway?  I assure you and  anyone else who gave of their wisdom and their precious time...I did anything I did from a place of ignorance and absolutely nothing from rudeness or a lack of appreciation. My best to each and everyone of you...keep up the great work.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted @RaymondZimmerman :)

Answer (score 0):

You can type `sudo bash` in the terminal. It will change into root user. If you have not set ant root password, it won't prompt for one.